# Java: Is 'tenured' memory the same as permgen?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, jvm, permgen

I am trying to gather information on an occasional issue we are having, where after a few weeks of operation the app slows down, works fine, slows down, works fine, with the intervals between being slow and working fine getting shorter and shorter.  My theory is that as time goes on we are garbage collecting more often.  The other key information is that we have occasionally experienced OOM PermGen issues.

I put enabled verbose:gc, and now see GC output in catalina.out.  I think I need to add the PrintGCDetails flag, however, based on the information here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

Enabled the latter flag will print out information on collection of "Tenured" memory. The question is, is that the memory that causes PermGen errors, or is it something different?  And if it is different, how can I log information that will show the PermGen space?

EDIT -- I cannot attach any of the jvm monitoring tools in this environment, unfortunately.

EDIT -- I added the said config options, as well as one for printing tenuring distribution, I get stuff like

```
27.701: [GC 27.701: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 2162688 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:    1906560 bytes,    1906560 total
- age   2:       2064 bytes,    1908624 total
- age   3:       5064 bytes,    1913688 total
- age   4:     650368 bytes,    2564056 total
: 35684K->2678K(38336K), 0.0068580 secs] 224179K->191173K(1065664K), 0.0069700 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Is the ParNew generation the permgen space?

and

```
 (concurrent mode failure): 25387K->31940K(1027328K), 0.2983200 secs] 50714K->31940K(1065664K), [CMS Perm : 35273K->35139K(35392K)], 0.2985210 secs] [Times: user=0.30 sys=0.00, real=0.30 secs] 
 (concurrent mode failure): 25356K->31941K(1027328K), 0.3032690 secs] 50861K->31941K(1065664K), [CMS Perm : 35264K->35129K(35392K)], 0.3034800 secs] [Times: user=0.30 sys=0.00, real=0.31 secs]
```

the failures are bothering me.

Thanx in advance

Comment: You could enable JMX and watch the Vm with VisualVM ...

Comment: @ZeissS, that is not an option in our environment, everything is locked down :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenured and PermGen are not the same, no. They are related, but not the same thing. The exact details depend on the implementation in the JVM you are using, but, from the document you linked:

*"A third generation closely related to the tenured generation is the permanent generation. The permanent generation is special because it holds data needed by the virtual machine to describe objects that do not have an equivalence at the Java language level. For example objects describing classes and methods are stored in the permanent generation."*

Interned Strings and class details and such are typically stored in PERM, whereas long lived Java objects are TENURED.

Here is a decent article explaining PermGen (and how to tweak it): http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation

Comment: thank you for the link.  I did miss the tenure vs permgen clarification on the article i posted.  I don't see anything in there about getting the jvm to dump permgen information -- did I miss that too?

Comment: this link indicates that the flag I am going to add does print out permgen info...http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2010/01/outofmemoryerror-on-heapspace-permgen.html

Comment: Yep, I think the regular -XX:+PrintGCDetails (with Sun VMs) will show the PermGen stats. Also, I see in later comments that it's a Grails app, that makes some sense that it would take a while for the PermGen thing to show up there, as you manipulate classes at runtime, etc. Simply bumping it up should help that, but for the general slowness you mentioned, you'll really want to figure out some what to run a profiler (maybe a test server that you put a huge load on to try to recreate the problem, in you're not allowed to monitor prod?).

Comment: I meant some "way" to run a profiler, and "if" you're not allowed to monitor prod (typos, sorry, but it's been too long since I noticed so not allowed to edit).

Comment: yeah we do have a qa environment I could attach to.  It takes weeks for the problem to occur in prod, we have quartz jobs running every few minutes, but that is just something I might have to deal with....I am updated the original question...

Answer (score 1):

Are you interning any Strings or loading any classes?

The two things I've had eat up permgen space are when you intern Strings that shouldn't be (thus making all sorts of ungarbagecollectable Strings hange around), and old class definitions caused by loading in new classes (usually from Tomcat redeploying, after a dozen or so this could happen for us).

I seem to remember that Tomcat 6 was better on the redeploy issue, and 7 was supposed to fix it, but that's off the top of my head.

Do you use any external libraries or native code libraries? I wouldn't be surprised if resources they leak count against permgen (just a guess).

Comment: this is not a restart issue.  We run out of permgen during normal operation.  Note this is a Grails app, so there are all sorts of things generated dynamically at runtime.  For this though, I am just trying to collect information -- how do i get the jvm to print out permgen info?

Comment: @gvgotcodes - The restarts just causes a large number of class loads. Every time you change a class's definition, Groovy would have to regenerate it, and that would cause a class load. That may be enough over time to cause the problem. As for finding out what's going on, you'll need to use the jstat tool (part of Java). It's tricky though. I can't get it to run on my server at the moment, it says it doesn't see Java. JXM monitoring (which you said is out) is easier.